# Probability Set Theory Question

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm working on the following problem but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do it:

Q: Let A and B be two arbitrary events in a sample space S. Prove or provide a counterexample:

If $P(A^c) = P(B) - P(A \cap B)$ then $P(B) = 1$

Drawing Venn diagrams I can see how this is true, as $A \subset B$, but I'm not sure how to formally prove this. Any help would be great!

Comment: One way is to split the sets into 'atoms', so in the above, $A \cap B$, $B \setminus A$, $A \setminus B$ and $(A  \cap B)^c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P$ be uniform on $S=\{1,2,3\}$ and let $A=\{1,2\}, B=\{2,3\}$.

$P(A \cap B) = P \{2\} = {1 \over 3}$.
$P(B) = P \{2,3\} = {2 \over 3}$.
$P(A^c) = P \{3\} = {1 \over 3}$.

Hence the equation holds but $P(B) \neq 1$.

All that one can really conclude is that $P (A \cup B)^c = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Not true. If $A^c\subseteq B$, then $B-A\cap B=A^c$, so $P(A^c)=P(B)-P(A\cap B)$ for any $B$.  This holds since $A^c$ and $A\cap B$ are mutually exclusive and add up to $B$.

Answer (score 0):

> Drawing Venn diagrams I can see how this is true, as $A \subset B$, but I'm not sure how to formally prove this. Any help would be great!

Nope.  (Unless you have a typo.)

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A^{\small\complement})&= \mathsf P(B)-\mathsf P(A\cap B) \\[1ex]&=\mathsf P(B)-\mathsf P(B)\,\mathsf P(A\mid B)\\[1ex]&=\mathsf P(B)\,\big(1-\mathsf P(A\mid B)\big)\\[1ex]&=\mathsf P(B)\,\mathsf P(A^{\small\complement}\mid B)\\[1ex]&=\mathsf P(A^{\small\complement}\cap B)\end{align}$$ Therefore the statement indicates that $A^{\small\complement}\cap B^{\small\complement}$ is a null set (which is not *quite* that $A^{\small\complement}\subseteq B$ ).

It would only entail that $\mathsf P(B)=1~~$ *when* $~~0<\mathsf P(A^{\small\complement})=\mathsf P(A^{\small\complement}\mid B)$, which requires … .